# pysimplegui table multiline text handling

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui

I am filling a pySimpleGui table from a log file. Most logs are single line but some multiline text are present.Table in layout is defined like this
`[sg.Table(key="mainTable",values=data, headings=header_list, display_row_numbers=False,col_widths=size_list,auto_size_columns=False, num_rows=40)]`
Currently multiline texts are overlapping over the next line text. Is there any way to show multiline text in a single cell or text-cropping is the only way?

Comment: Please post your minimal reproductible example, with a screenshot of what happens.

Answer (score 2):

If you look into their [QT Table](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/PySimpleGUIQt/PySimpleGUIQt.py#L3314) or [Web Table](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/PySimpleGUIWeb/PySimpleGUIWeb.py) accepting `auto_size_columns` and ignoring it for Table specifically like in [QT not using it for Table but for Tree](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/PySimpleGUIQt/PySimpleGUIQt.py#L7052) and [Web its commented](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/PySimpleGUIWeb/PySimpleGUIWeb.py#L5005)!

After checking their allowed options and seeing if we could apply `setWordWrap` directly on QTTable or similar on anything on Widget, it's hard to even find it.

But on other hand, they do have many examples to custom build a tabular format: [Demo_Table_Simulation.py](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Table_Simulation.py)

Here is what I tried to generate a custom table:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import csv
import math

# Show CSV data in Table
sg.theme('Dark Red')

def table_example():
    filename = sg.popup_get_file('addresses.csv', no_window=True, file_types=(("CSV Files","*.csv"),))
    # --- populate table with file contents --- #
    if filename == '':
        return
    data = []
    header_list = []
    button = sg.popup_yes_no('Does this file have column names already?')
    if filename is not None:
        with open(filename, "r") as infile:
            reader = csv.reader(infile)
            if button == 'Yes':
                header_list = next(reader)
            try:
                data = list(reader)  # read everything else into a list of rows
                if button == 'No':
                    header_list = ['column' + str(x) for x in range(len(data[0]))]
            except:
                sg.popup_error('Error reading file')
                return
    sg.set_options(element_padding=(0, 0))

    values = []
    for row in data:
        # Calculate the size of sg.Text based on the length of the text greater than some size
        values.append([sg.Text(i, size=(15, math.ceil(1 if len(i) <= 15 else len(i)/15))) for i in row])

        # Add a horizontal separator with length and calculate the width
        length=15*len(values[0])
        values.append([sg.Text('_'*length)])


    input_rows = [[sg.Input(size=(15,1), pad=(0,0)) for col in range(4)] for row in range(10)]

    layout = values

    window = sg.Window('Table', layout, grab_anywhere=False)
    event, values = window.read()

    window.close()

table_example()
```

The output looks something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no option to wrap text in `sg.Tree` or `ttk.Treeview`.

As I know, the only way is to insert '\n' into your text, then it will wrap to next line.

To show all lines in a row, you have to set option `row_height` large enough to fit all lines.
Here, another problem will be generated for `row_height`.

- You won't see next line if row height is too small to shown all wrap lines.
- If you set `row_height` large enough, you will still see same space occupied if only one line.
- Text will be aligned vertical center

It seems there's no way to set row height for different rows.

example here,

```py
import textwrap
from random import randint, choice
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def wrap(string, lenght=15):
    return '\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(string, lenght))

sg.theme('DarkBlue')
sg.set_options(font=('Courier New', 12))

column_width = 15
word = "1234567890"*5

data = [[wrap(word[:randint(1, 50)], column_width) for col in range(4)] for row in range(30)]
header_list = [f'Column {i}' for i in range(4)]
size_list = [column_width+2]*4

layout = [
    [sg.Table(
        key="-TREE-",
        values=data,
        headings=header_list,
        display_row_numbers=False,
        col_widths=size_list,
        auto_size_columns=False,
        num_rows=10,
        row_height=80, 
        alternating_row_color='green',
        )],
]

window = sg.Window('Tree Element Test', layout, finalize=True)
tree = window['-TREE-'].Widget

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Cancel'):
        break

window.close()
```

Another way is more difficult to implement, using other elements to simulate a tree or a table, like example from [Nagaraj Tantri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/308565/nagaraj-tantri)